# Multiple conditions on an Outlook item in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm querying Outlook database through Excel VBA, and I want to apply two conditions on the value of a user defined property. The following code, which has both conditions in the same "If" statement

```
Set cat1 = CurrentItem.UserProperties.Find("catniveau1")
If cat1 <> "" and Not (cat1 Is Nothing) Then
```

,raises the following error :  "Object variable or With block variable not set". However, having two separate "if" statements is working fine :

```
Set cat1 = CurrentItem.UserProperties.Find("catniveau1")
If Not (cat1 Is Nothing) Then 
  If cat1 <> "" Then
```

Is there a way to apply both conditions on the same "if" statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to evaluate both conditions at the same time because of logical connections "timing", let me explain.

1. cat1 is a range (needs to be determined what is going to be first)
   Since cat1 may or may not be defined you can't evaluate if its <> "".
2. cat1 <> "" it needs to evaluate what the range is.
   I know the "human" thinking may be at the same time, but, summarizing:

A)The variable needs to be solved first as range to ...

B)Be evaluated if <> "",

I don't understand why would you need to evaluate `if <>""` again -if it didn't find the value it would be nothing- why not only leave the statement `If Not (cat1 Is Nothing) Then` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need both conditions as Nothing and "" are possible values in my case.  "" is a possible choice from listbox in my (probably not optimal) custom form.

Comment: I'm kind of confused, according to the question 
Set cat1 = CurrentItem.UserProperties.Find("catniveau1")
If cat1 <> "" and Not (cat1 Is Nothing) Then  'where would an additional value would be taken from if it is just set above?
1. If I'm guessing right, then "catniveau" is a variable taken from the listbox in your userform, why don't you set listbox style property to  2- fmstyledropdownlist so user can't select other thing than the one populated there? 2. Why don't you add an OK button to the form, and evaluate before if <>"" was selected?

Comment: I'm actually forcing the user to select only what's populated in the listbox. Listbox are populated in VBS to be able to affect the content of one list by the choice made with another one. So I'm the guilty one who, for some practical reasons, decided to add the "" choice in some listbox. Probably there is a better way to do what I did (but after some struggling to make it work in different context - copy, displacement of appointment, etc.- I think I'm gonna let it as it is).